# JSON file generated by PHP has application/octet-stream mime type

Tags: php, json, mime-types

I have a script that generates a JSON file from data.
I have a second script that read files from a directory to take only JSON ones and insert them in DB.

The problem is that the second script detects "application/octet-stream" MIME type from my generated files instead of `application/json`

I don't want to allow `application/octet-stream` MIME type as it can be pretty anything (for security reason: that second script load all `json` file in the directory (not only the generated ones)).

Is there then anyway to "set" a MIME type for a file?

The code that generate the file :

```
if($r_handle = fopen($s_file_name, 'w+')){
    fwrite($r_handle, json_encode($o_datas, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG));
    fclose($r_handle);
    return;
}
```

The code that read JSON files :

```
$o_finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$a_mimes =& get_mimes();
if(is_dir($s_dir) && $r_handle = opendir($s_dir)){
    while($s_file = readdir($r_handle)){
        $s_file_path = $s_dir.$s_file;
        $s_mime      = finfo_file($o_finfo, $s_file_path);
        if(!in_array($s_file, array('.', '..')) && in_array($s_mime, $a_mimes['json'])){
            // Some code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot "set" a MIME type. Finfo is just *guessing* as best it can. "application/octet-stream" pretty much mean "dunno, it's a file I guess". Which is technical a correct answer…

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, you could set the content-type in `header()` and `fopen()` the file in PHP, right?

Comment: @SteveKnau : Can I do `header()` then `fopen()` then `fwrite()` then `fclose()` ?

Comment: That won't do anything useful, no.

Comment: Indeed, I tried... so far, no news. Guess I'll have to rely on the file extension...

Comment: Specifically for JSON and similar data formats with a distinct file extension: try to parse it as JSON. If that fails, it's either the wrong file extension or a broken file. Of course try not to let your server be exploited in the process, e.g. by trying to parse a 2GB JSON file into memory…

Comment: I already have a control on the data format inside the file (using JSON schema : https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema)

Comment: What is your filename? Is it saved as `.json`?

Comment: @Arcanyx yes it is, the filename is "batch.json"

Answer (score 1):

The [fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo) extension (as similar tools like the [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) Unix command) basically searches for signatures defined in a database (called "magic"). If I'm not wrong, PHP's magic database is currently compiled into the extension binary file so you can't peek at it but you'll probably have a similar database in your system. I have Apache's at `C:\Apache24\conf.magic` and this is the entry for JPEG:

```
# JPEG images
0   beshort     0xffd8      image/jpeg
```

Anything that starts with `0xffd8` is a picture. Done!

[image: JPEG file in hex editor]

I'm not particularly familiar with the format but it doesn't seem to even *look* for JSON. And, as you may already be guessing, the overall utility is by no means a security feature. It's just a helper tool to figure out what a file may contain. It's very handy if e.g. you've recovered files with no extension from a damaged disk.

---

MIME types are cool. You set `application/json` and everybody knows it's JSON. Straightforward and simple, isn't it. There're only two caveats:

- File systems (many of them actually invented before MIME types) store many file attributes (name, last modification date, permissions, sometimes even icons...) but not MIME types. (Sure, there's probably some academic file system that does, but it's not the case of FAT32, NTFS, ext4...). It doesn't normally add valuable information, it's yet another token to keep updated and it's particularly non-portable (copy your files to a thumb drive and they're gone).
- It's still not a security feature. If I can forge the file contents, what prevents me from forging the MIME type?

---

So, what can you do? The best alternative is: nothing at all.

Just parse the file as JSON and detect whether it failed. You need to do it anyway and it tells you everything you need to do. JSON is just plain text data. Maybe add some checks to prevent very large files (again, you should be doing it anyway in your file upload) and add a `$depth` check but that's all.

```
if (json_decode($s_file_path, true, 32)!==null || json_last_error()!==JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    // Valid JSON
}
```